# Allow change in property only from one specific class

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Suppose I have a class  `Participant` which looks like this

`Participant.h`

```
@interface Participant : NSObject
    @property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString *name;
    @property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString *id;

@end
```

Here properties are `readonly` because I don't want anyone using this interface to change it

Besides  `ParticipantManager.h`

What changes should I do in `Participant` class and how would I create `ParticipantManager` such that only `ParticipantManager` can change properties of `Participant`

### More context

I get an event from `react-native` when value changes. to keep things in sync, I want my interface  `ParticipantManager` to only change the values.

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>

@interface ParticipantManager : RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule>

@end
```

**^^** Above class should only be able to change properties of `Participant` class

For a user to change a value, he would call `changeName` method, which will send an event back to `react-native` where `react-native` would change value and send back to native code

### what I have tried.

So, I thought about using class extensions concept but I am getting an error.

Here is what I did

I create  `Participant+Private.h` which implements setName method

```
#import " Participant.h" 

interface Participant() 
- (void)setName:(NSString)name
- (void)setId:(NSString)name
@end
```

PS: I implemented setName and setId method in `Participant.h`

```
- (void)setName:(NSString)name {
_name = name; 
}
```

but then when I am using it in my  `ParticipantManager.h`, it is throwing error

> No visible @interface for  `Participant`declares the selector
> `setName`

I am using it like this

```
#import "Participant+Private.h"

    NSString* value = @"varun";
    [[Participant sharedInstance] setName:value];
```

Can someone help me in fixing error?

Slightly detailed question here:
[No visible @interface for Participant declares the selector setName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68295167/no-visible-interface-for-participantdeclares-the-selector-setname)

Comment: "Suppose I have a coco touch class Participant.h" You don't. Participant.h is the name of a file, not a class; and Participant is the name of _your_ class, not a Cocoa Touch class.

Comment: Edited question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C doesn't provide that sort of reasoned privacy, e.g. "I am private to everyone except one other specific class which I hereby name". (Actually, I don't know any language that behaves that way, but that's not to say that there are no such languages of course.)

If this is a framework, you can use `@package` privacy to confine the privacy of something to other classes in the same framework.

Otherwise, Objective-C generally solves the visibility problem by importing headers, so if you put public accessors for Participant into a header and the only class that imports that header is ParticipantManager, then only ParticipantManager sees them.

Comment: thanks a lot for answering. I tried doing it using class extension but I am getting an error. 

I have updated the question, Can you please check `what I have tried` heading?